# How does JQuery's .click() work behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This question is just out of curiosity. I want to know how jquery's .click() works behind the scenes.

For instance if I create a button:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click me!" />
```

Then I have the following jquery code:

```
$('#myButton').click( function() {
    alert("I have been clicked.");
});
```

How does jquery make it so that my function is called when the button is clicked?

At first I thought it would add the `onClick=""` attribute to the button's tag, but when I inspected the page with Firebug I just saw:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click me!" />
```

So what does jquery do behind the scenes?

Comment: For future reference, you can also check the jQuery source to see exactly what's going on. It's not always clear (so your question is totally reasonable to ask), but worth checking out. This site is really useful for that: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on the browser.

If you're using a browser that supports `addEventListener()`, they'll add a handler using that.

Although I'm pretty sure they're actually attaching a function that first repairs/normalizes the `event` object, then checks the DOM element for the `jQuery12345...` property and looks up the handler in `jQuery.cache` and invokes it.

If you log your element to the console, you'll see a property that looks something like:

```
jQuery1296081364954: 1
```

Then if you log that number to the console from `jQuery.cache`, you'll see the associated data.

```
console.log(jQuery.cache[1]);
```

...which will give a structure something like this:

```
{
   events:{
      click:[
         { /* object containing data relevant to the first click handler */ }
      ]
   },
   handle:{ /* this may be what initially gets called. Not sure. */ }
}
```

Because jQuery does normalize the event object, it isn't quite as simple as just assigning a a handler for you and calling it. I believe it is also done with the cache in order to avoid memory leaks in older browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Uses the DOM event model, which is also what happens when you add the onClick(). so basically it registers a listener for the button to fire off the click event and then performs the code you told it to.

Answer (score 1):

the function is attached to the onclick event on your input but not using the html declaration but plain javascript. Instead of looking in the html code take a look at the DOM tab in firebug, you should find it there.

In plain javascript it's like

```
    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click',function () { alert('hello!');},false);
```

Comment: Not accurate.. that sample you gave is overwriting existing events and allows one event - jQuery won't overwrite and allow as many events as you like.