# Add onclick event to a dynamic-created anchor with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this question [Use JQuery to build an anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304342/use-jquery-to-build-an-anchor) here to build an anchor dynamically with JQuery.

I want to know how can I add the onclick event to my hyperlink?

I've been trying to do this, but nothing happens. The onclick event is never added.

```
function init(){
   var btnSave = "<a id=\"btnSave\">Save</a> "
   $(btnSave).on("click", {Arg1 : "1", Arg2: "2"}, save)
   var div = $("#myDiv");
   div.html(btnSave);
}

function save(e){
   var data = e.data;
   var arg1 = data.Arg1;
   var arg2 = data.Arg2;
   //...
}
```

I know that I can "embeed" the onclick like this:

```
   var btnSave = "<a id=\"btnSave\" onclick=\"" + ... + "\">Save</a> "
```

But the way I'm trying to do, it looks like cleaner in my opinion. I accept another cleaner option. Thanks.

My function save is planned to be reused many times with other hyperlinks the arguments are differents.

---

**Update**

According to suggestions I changed it to this, but still cannot see the onclick added to my HTML element.

```
function init(){
   var btnSave = $("<a id='btnSave'></a>").html("Save").on("click", {Arg1 : "1", Arg2: "2"}, save);
   $("#myDiv").html(btnSave);
}
```

In the console of Google chrome I test the value of the btnSave and the console logs this

```
"<a id="btnSave">Save</a>"
```

Comment: How are you clicking the anchor? It's not attached to the DOM and the reference to it is local to the init function.

Comment: My bad, I copied only a part of it. I updated the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JQuery's .click() work behind the scenes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810766/how-does-jquerys-click-work-behind-the-scenes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code:

```
div.html(btnSave);
```

… is equivalent to this:

```
div.html("<a id=\"btnSave\">Save</a> ");
```

The anchor created with the following code is essentially being lost, because it isn't ever attached to the DOM:

```
$(btnSave).on("click", {Arg1 : "1", Arg2: "2"}, save);
```

Instead, you could store that anchor in a new variable, which you can put in the DIV:

```
function init(){
  var btnSave = "<a id=\"btnSave\">Save</a> ",
      anchor = $(btnSave).on("click", {Arg1 : "1", Arg2: "2"}, save);

  var div = $("#myDiv");
  div.html(anchor);
}
```

Or more simply:

```
function init(){
  var anchor= $('<a id="btnSave">Save</a> ')
                .on('click', {Arg1 : '1', Arg2: '2'}, save)

  $('#myDiv').html(anchor);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried that but look my updated question. The onclick is not added.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/2nqobhea/.  Click Save, and you'll see the alert.  You won't see the click event in the Elements console.

Comment: Even simpler: `function init(){ $('<a href="#">Save</a>').on('click', {Arg1 : '1', Arg2: '2'}, save).appendTo('#myDiv');}`. Add `return false` to function save.

Comment: `appendTo()` will add the anchor after existing elements in `#myDiv`, which may not be what the OP wants.  `return false` is needed if the anchor has an `href`, which isn't the case in the posted code, but may very well exist in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `id` or the selector of the element you don't need to add any events when adding the element. You can simply add the following into your JS code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', save);
```

This will work with all dynamically added elements.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2nqobhea/1/